# Cannot send mail in asp.net in Hiox server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to send mail in HIOX server. What should be given for host address? Is it my IP or my domain name? Do I need to specify any credentials.? If so where should I create? Do I need to add anything in Web.config? How does sending mail actually work.? Can someone take me through this. It would be really helpful.

```
           MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
           msg.To.Add("toaddress@gmail.com");
           MailAddress address = new MailAddress("fromaddress@gmail.com");
            msg.From = address;
            msg.Subject = "Hi";
            msg.Body = "welcome";

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "???"; // my domain name is "iqubekct.in"
            client.Port = 25;
            client.Send(msg);
            Response.Write("Sent..!!!");
```

Comment: Generally the host is a valid email server that accepts relay requests. Look at your MX records for some hints as to what to use.

Comment: There is no option to view MX records. It is not available in HIOX.

Comment: `Rahul` is this going to be run from your company's `HOST` if so ask your admin what your email hostname is for example `mail.something.net` also wrap the `client.Send()` Method around a try{}catch{} in the event that you need to report on errors also if your `Email requires credentials`  then you need something like the following `NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(username, password);`

Comment: Have you though about consulting the HIOX FAQ for this http://hioxindia.com/faq/domain-hosting/smtp-server-name.php